# Gradle build issue | Getting "NEGOTIATE authentication error"

Tags: build.gradle

When i try to build my project via gradle by running command "gradle build"
it gives me following error :
*NEGOTIATE authentication error: Invalid name provided (Mechanism level: KrbException: Cannot locate default realm)*

In gradle.properties I have set proxy settings accurately.
Help me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

My gradle.properties i slike below :

systemProp.http.proxyHost=**someIP**

systemProp.http.proxyPort=**4145**

systemProp.https.proxyHost=**someIP**

systemProp.https.proxyPort=**4145**

systemProp.http.proxyUser=**myusername**

systemProp.http.proxyPassword=**mypassword**

systemProp.https.proxyUser=**myusername**

systemProp.https.proxyPassword=**mypassword**